# Wordpress prefix dynamic value to custom taxonomy url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-taxonomy

I have two custom taxonomies 'edition' and 'features'

I'd like wordpress to allow me to prefix the slug of features with a value from editions.

For example if i go here;

> mysite.com/asia/features/interviews/

Wordpress would translate the url to;

> mysite.com/index.php?features=interview&edition=asia

and then loading the features taxonomy template where i can then grab the edition **query_var** and filter the templates accordingly.

I'm thinking playing around with **add_rewrite_rule** would sort it am not sure.

Any help appreciated

Cheers

**UPDATE**

Ok I think I'm semi on the right lines, I have a rewrite rule written;

```
RewriteRule ^(media|asia|uk)/([^/]+/)*(^/)? index.php?feature=$2&department=$1
```

Which takes a url like;

```
www.mysite.com/media/features/interviews/face-to-face/
```

but it converts it to;

```
index.php?feature=face-to-face/&department=asia
```

Some how I need to get rid of the last / but I'm not proficient enough in regular expressions to work it out.

any ideas?

Comment: This is now solved. The correct rewrite was;

`RewriteRule ^(media|asia|uk)/([^/]+/)*([^/]+)/? index.php?feature=$3&department=$1`

So now i can prefix the taxonomy urls with media, asia or uk and it will sucsessfully jump to the correct taxonomy term page

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the correct rule was;

```
RewriteRule ^(media|asia|uk)/([^/]+/)*([^/]+)/? index.php?feature=$3&department=$1
```