# Add dynamic prefix in WordPress page url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I need to add dynamic prefix in page url.

You can help with how can I achieve this with [Rewrite_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_rewrite_rules)

**Problem**

In my WordPress website, I've few pages which I want to access using **prefix** before the page name in URL. For example, normally page is accessible using

```
http://example.com/page-name
```

I want to add **dynamic prefix**(location) before the page name. So I want to access the page like below

```
http://example.com/country/state/page-name
```

**What I tried so far:**

I tried to use below filter to add rewrite tag just before the page name in url.

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'custom_rewrite_rules' ), 1, 0 ); 
 /*
* Rewrite page urls
* adding prefix to page urls
* @doc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613789/wordpress-rewrite-add-base-prefix-to-pages-only
*/
function custom_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    // add rewrite tag for location
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%region%", '([^/]+)', 'region=' );

    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '%region%/%pagename%';        


}// end func
```

Above action hook allows me to have dynamic page url in frontend and in backend.
For example, I can see page urls are now

```
http://example.com/%region%/page-name
```

**What I need**

As I have dynamic url's generated now, I want to replace **%region%** part of the url with the location string I want, It could be just **country** name or **country/state** name combination.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am trying to solve pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Not yet, I've tried @user5200704 answer, but I stuck with the problem. I just need to change url's in the frontend, in backend url shoud be with %region% rewrite tag. Also it should load the same page doesn't matter what the prefix is. currently all the solution I tried gives me 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Change page link using wordpress filter

```
add_filter( '_get_page_link', 'custom_region_page_link', 10, 2 );

function custom_region_page_link( $link, $post_id ){
    //$slug = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', true );
    $link = str_replace('%region%', 'india', $link);
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: It also replaces urls in backend, it should remain http://example.com/%region%/page-name in backend. Only in front end if  want to change it with region(country or state) we can replace it with a string. we might need rewrite rule as well.

Comment: you can check conditionally rewrite rule is very well.
if( ! is_admin() ){
  // replace code here 
  $link = str_replace('%region%', 'india', $link);
}

Comment: Ah ok. I've just found this post which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251287/wordpress-prefix-dynamic-value-to-custom-taxonomy-url

Comment: @user5200704 I can successfully replace the string, But that gives me 404 because WordPress thinks its a different page. I want to load the same page. For example, example.com/india/test-page should show the content of example.com/test-page. prefix should be disregarded. We need rewrite rule for that. I cant make it work.

Comment: I test in my local environment it's working. I think need flush rules to update wordpress new page structure.
$wp_rewrite->page_structure after  
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules

Comment: Can you help me with how can i write rewrite rule once I have http://example.com/country/state/pagename and I just want to show same page [pagename]. Thanks for helping me so far. Bounty is yours.